# It is possible to install .ipa file from Mac PC (macOS running in VMWare) without Apple id in my Apple iPhone?

Tags: ios

I use Windows 10 PC and working with macOS by the help of VMWare. I develop an iOS application using Xcode and the language used is Swift. I am trying to install my application to my Apple iPhone by using iTools and iTunes. I don't have an Apple Id. But this installation is impossible without an Apple Id. Is there any other way to install application (.ipa file) into my Apple mobile without Apple Id?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i do the same.
The VM player has the option to connect the device (found on top right corner when phone is connected to usb) which you can chose to connect your iphone. 
Once connected (and itunes installed in VM), you can use xcode to deploy to the connected device.
You will need apple developer account only when you need to distribute the app to other people on appstore.

You will need a free apple id entered into xcode, no need to signup for developer account for now.

Comment: Thank you. if i need to distribute my app i have to purchase the developer acccount right?
There is three type of accounts (Enterprise, Organisation, Individuals)
So what is the difference between these accounts , limit of client and please advice me which account is better.

Comment: Developer account is needed for distribution to public. individual is the way to go unless you have a registered company / planned one .